# Tapping Neutral in Service Entrance

Tags: electrical-panel

(Back to original message because tapping utility pole ground rod directly is not good idea because in our country, robbers like to steal wiring, so if they remove the neutral, and they form a series, they can get shock or worse...)

Background for the experts who have helped me so much in the past. This is my last question. I need to activate grounding before I do all the projects I have asked advices the past month.

In my country the Philippines. 99.9999% of homes don't have any grounding. This is because we never use neutral to produce 120v. We only use 240v. And we have the same split phase power system as the US because they created our ac power system. But after they left and to promote national patriotism, we outlawed use of any 120v so we won't rely on products from the US (this is what the utility company exactly told me).

Also in my country. Contractors omit the third grounding wire because all our appliances don't have any third grounding wire. Even Refrigerators have only 2 prong plug.

Now I need to tap the neutral outside the service entrance directly to my Siemens panel. This is for protection in case hot wire touches the enclosure (so it can trip the breakers. I know the reasons and the rules for grounding and only bonding it at the panel). I want to know what kind of metal connector that I can use to connect or tap a AWG 10 side by side with the AWG 0/1 neutral wire in the service entrance, one that will not rust even after exposed to sun and rains for decades. Is there such a connector? I won't connect them end to end but just tap the open wire at the middle body of it (see photo below). It is much larger than my AWG 10. What connector can do that?

This is our service entrance neutral wire hanging (not inserted into the service entrance).

[image: 1]

Here all our apartments have 2 wire going into the conduit and my home is 20 meters inside the compound, therefore I need to connect the AWG 10 by attaching it outside the house frames on the way to the Siemens neutral conductor lugs. I can't do the usual way of wiring it via the service entrance and main panels because I can no longer insert the wires 20 meters away. See.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [split bolt](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=f6L2W8e1KYyY_QbNx4b4DQ&q=split%20bolt%20connector&oq=split%20bolt%20&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.1258.3879..7311...0.0..0.144.1485.0j12......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i131j0i20i263j0i131i10.45r6oocgDxE) connector would seem to be right for this. Use electrical joint compound (such as Burndy Penetrox) then tape over the joint.

However, you would have to separate the neutral/ground enough from the insulated conductors and then tape over the split bolt and maybe interpose a piece of plastic or rubber so that it would not over time wear a hole in the insulation and cause a short.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86211/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-stewart-tapping-neutral-in-service-entrance).