# 8/2 wire for 240v EV charger

Tags: electrical, ground

I have installed an EV level 2 charger in my garage. It is a 30 amp charger. It is around 8 feet away from the breaker box. I used 8/2 wire to be on the safe side for future possible upgrades and used a 2 pole 40 amp breaker, as required by the EVSE instructions.

The EV charger is working fine. The question I have is that the two hot wires are 8 gauge but the ground wire is a bare 10 gauge wire. Is this OK or should I replace the ground with an 8 gauge wire?

Comment: If the data plate on the charger calls for a 30A circuit, you should use a 30A breaker to protect it.  Using bigger wire is fine, but the breaker needs to be sized for the "appliance" requirements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are ground wires required to be so large if a short results in an immediate breaker trip?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148654/why-are-ground-wires-required-to-be-so-large-if-a-short-results-in-an-immediate), and [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/151175/43874) specifically has the NEC chart that lists the conductor sizes.   You should be fine.

Comment: JPhil1618 Thank you for your reply. The appliance requires a 40 amp breaker. My concern is with the ground wire being thinner than the 2 hot wires.

Comment: For "the next time" consider that it's usually easy to run conduit 8 feet, and if the device's terminals go to 75C (and your breakers do - mine do, certainly) you can carry more current on THHN in conduit than you can on "the same size wire" as a cable (limited to 60C rating.) In the case of 8 Ga copper, 50 rather than 40 A.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, a 10 AWG ground wire is fine for up to a 60A circuit.

The 8/2 Romex (NM) cable is good for amperage up to 40 amps. However, **the breaker must match the socket / EV charger spec**.  If the socket is a NEMA 6-30 or 14-30, the breaker must be 30A.  If the EV charger docs specify 30A breaker, then that must be so.

Again, the 8/2 cable is perfectly fine for 30A or really any size *up to* 40A.  So if your spec calls for a 30A breaker, you only need to change the breaker. 30A sockets will accept #8 wire.

It is possible that a 30A-nameplate charger might want a 40A breaker. The documentation will tell the tale.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So to make sure I have a good enough understanding of this thing, the ground wire is actually not in constant use and it is only there in case of a short or malfunction, that's why it does not need to be as thick as the 2 hot wires, right?

Comment: @Ali Correct.  Flow on equipment safety ground only occurs during fault conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. You guys are AWESOME.

Answer (score -1):

#10 then is <s>only good for 30 amps</s> , correct this before too many people see this

As requested, correcting this: using the chart from https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/151175/18078

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/160319)

Comment: You are incorrect, and the question is more than 2 years old. But mostly, you're incorrect about the specific case of sizing of grounding conductors, which is the question here.